# what about developing on Acer mobile

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

is it normal using windows mobile 6.5 SDK or I need more tools ? and can I access WIFI adapter using Windows Mobile 6.5 SDK ?

Answer (score 3):

You can access it with OpenNetCF:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446491.aspx